# How do I setup a Codeblocks project on Windows 10 to compile and link a static SFML project?

Tags: c++, linker, windows-10, codeblocks, sfml

My advance appologies for being hopeless at Windows development. I am by no means a Windows developer and my understanding of how to write, compile and link C++ code on a Windows system is limited to say the least.

I am having difficulty trying to compile and link a SFML project on a Windows 10 system with the CodeBlocks IDE.

I am trying to link this project with static linking, not dynamic linking. Again I have virtually no idea how the two different methods work in detail, I just know that if I ship a static linked binary to another Windows 10 user it is much more likely to "just work" on their system.

List of things I did:

- Downloaded the latest version of CodeBlocks with MINGW integration.
- Installed, default options
- Downloaded the latest version of SFML (32bit MINGW version)
- Extracted the zip file (SFML) to my home directory
- Created a new codeblocks project (console application) and followed the instructions to set the compiler and linker options

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php

It works fine for dynamic linking, but requires me to copy the .dll files to the same dir as the produced executable file (produced from compilation of my C++ code).

I tried to change to static linking, changing the names of the linker libs with the `-s` or `-s-d` suffix, and adding the define `SMFL_STATIC` option to global (release and debug) options. I also added the opengl32, freetype, winmm and gdi32 link libs, **before** their respective sfml link libs.

When trying to compile I get the following linker errors

```
cannot find -lfreetype
cannot find -lsfml-graphics-s-d
cannot find -lsfml-window-s-d
cannot find -lsfml-system-s-d
```

in Release mode, similar errors are produced.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you build the static libraries? Have you checked that they exist in your SFML folder? Did you take care to add the libraries in the correct order? For the external dependencies like freetype you need to make sure they also exist and can be found.

Comment: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=27075.0 may have related info.

Comment: @super No I didn't build the libraries myself. Perhaps that is a misunderstanding on my part. Am I required to build them from source in order to static link?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be that you either have the wrong compiler (see below) or you haven't defined the library directory as mentioned in the linked tutorial.

---

There are four common things to consider when using SFML (and essentially any other C++ library) on Windows.

- Compiler versions have to fully match
- Make sure to not mix x86 and x64
- Settings need to be specified for the correct configuration
- When linking libraries statically, you also need to link the dependencies

### Compiler versions have to fully match

Since C++ doesn't have a standardized ABI, the generated libraries will never be reusable between compilers. Yes, sometimes "it works", but it can break at any point and there's no guarantee.

We strongly recommend to either use the compilers linked on the [SFML Download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/) or build SFML from source with your current compiler.

If you got the latest stable Code::Blocks version with MinGW as stated, you should also be able to get a [snapshot build of SFML](https://artifacts.sfml-dev.org/by-branch/master/), which should be using the same compiler.

**Note:** One exception to this rule is Visual Studio, where VS 2017 binaries are compatible with VS 2019 (and maybe VS 2022?).

### Make sure to not mix x86 and x64

When you download a 32-bits (x86) version of SFML, you also need a 32-bits version of your compiler. When you download a 64-bits (x64) version of SFML, you also need a 64-bits version of your compiler.

Make sure you double check your compiler configuration that you've selected the correct bit-ness.

**Note:** For Visual Studio you need to select the correct compiler architecture in the IDE, usually positioned right next to the run button.

### Settings need to be specified for the correct configuration

Project configurations are usually spread across the matrix built from the types:

- Debug / Release / All
- x86 / x64 (for VS)

Make sure when you add the settings for library paths and include paths that it's not just set for debug or release and ends up missing in either or the other configuration.

Also make sure you're not setting up debug libraries (with the `-d` suffix) in release mode or release libraries (without any suffix) in debug mode.

### When linking libraries statically, you also need to link the dependencies

The SFML static libraries don't contain any symbols of any of its dependencies, that means, in your final application you have to link static SFML and all its dependencies.

As a short summary you can think of static libraries like an archive of object files. These object files will directly be linking into your application, like you link your own source file object files. As such, the SFML static libraries only contain object files of SFML itself and not of other libraries as well.

---

### Troubleshooting

If nothing seems to help, then you should enable [verbose compiler & linker output](https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#tr-grl-verbose-ide), that we you see exactly which commands are invoked and one can quickly spot the missing statements.